# Run command after container start up

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to execute command after docker container start. 
Here is my Dockerfile

```
FROM mysite:myport/mongo:3.6
EXPOSE 27017
ADD mongo.js /data/mongodb/scripts/
```

here is my docker-compose.yml

```
mongo:
    image: test-mongo
    container_name: test-mongo
    hostname: mongo
    expose:
      - "27017"
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    command: mongo --eval load("/data/mongodb/scripts/mongo.js")
```

docker-compose --no-ansi up returns me

```
Creating test-mongo ...
Creating test-mongo ... done
Attaching to test-mongo
test-mongo | MongoDB shell version v3.6.5
test-mongo | connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017
test-mongo | 2018-06-09T15:46:50.229+0000 W NETWORK  [thread1] Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017, in(checking socket for error after poll), rea
son: Connection refused
test-mongo | 2018-06-09T15:46:50.229+0000 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed :
test-mongo | connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:251:13
test-mongo | @(connect):1:6
test-mongo | exception: connect failed
test-mongo exited with code 1
```

I don't uderstand how can I load my file **after** mongodb is started

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By passing a `command` in your `docker-compose.yaml`, you are *overriding* the normal behavior of the `mongo` image -- so the mongo server is never starting.  The way you would typically handle this is to put your script into a *second* image, and then start a second container as part of your `docker-compose.yaml` that makes a network connection to the mongo server.  Something like:

```
version: "3"

services:
  mongo:
    image: mongo

  client:
    image: my-mongo-client
    restart: on-failure
    command: mongo --host mongo --eval load("/data/mongodb/scripts/mongo.js")
```

The `restart` directive will cause the client container to restart
automatically on failure, which is necessary because it may try to
connect before the mongo server is available to handle connections.

Comment: `command: mongo --host mongo --eval "load(\"/data/mongodb/scripts/mongo.js\")"` this variant is working

Answer (score 4):

If all you're trying to do is initialize a new database, such as creating a new schema and adding a user, you can create an initialization script and load it into the container. From the Docker Hub [documentation](https://hub.docker.com/_/mongo):

> When a container is started for the first time it will execute files with extensions .sh and .js that are found in /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d. Files will be executed in alphabetical order. .js files will be executed by mongo using the database specified by the MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE variable, if it is present, or test otherwise. You may also switch databases within the .js script.